# Text outside of footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add text to my footer but my second and third texts are below my footer. What can I do to put it inside my footer? I know it has something to do with block-level but what is it exactly that needs to be done. Please and thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

```css
#footer {
  background: #2e3131;
  position: relative;
  height: 165px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  clear: both;
}

.footer-contact {
  color: #fff;
}

.headquaters {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.social-media {
  float: right;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 238);
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="footer-contact">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <p>Phone: (777) 777-7777</p>
    <p>Cell: (347) 777-7777</p>
    <p>E-mail: someone@gmail.com</p>
  </div>

  <div class="headquaters">
    <h3>Locations</h3>
    <p>90 John Street</p>
  </div>


  <div class="social-media">
    <h3>Follow our social media</h3>
    <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf230;</i>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: you can use `float` like some of the answers below, but I recommend using `flexbox`:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 

or you can use `twitter-bootstrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `margin-top:-100px;` and give `float` to `div` for setting inline in your `footer` height

```css
#footer {
  background: #2e3131;
  position: relative;
  height: 165px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.footer-contact {
  color: #fff;
      float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.headquaters {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);    
  float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.social-media {
  float: right;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 238);
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
          <div class="footer-contact">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
              <p>Phone: (777) 777-7777</p>
              <p>Cell: (347) 777-7777</p>
              <p>E-mail: someone@gmail.com</p>
            </div>

            <div class="headquaters">
              <h3>Locations</h3>
                <p>90 John Street</p>
            </div>


              <div class="social-media">
               <h3>Follow our social media</h3> 
                <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf230;</i>
                  </div>

                   </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are adding height in px to the #footer, what you need to do is to increase the height.

```
#footer {
  background: #2e3131;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  clear: both;
}
```

or you can check [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJbMzQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following style in your footer: `#footer {width:100%; display:inline-block;}`

```css
#footer {
  background: #2e3131;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.footer-contact {
  color: #fff;
  float:left;
}

.headquaters {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  float:left;
}

.social-media {
  float: right;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 238);
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
          <div class="footer-contact">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
              <p>Phone: (777) 777-7777</p>
              <p>Cell: (347) 777-7777</p>
              <p>E-mail: someone@gmail.com</p>
            </div>

            <div class="headquaters">
              <h3>Locations</h3>
                <p>90 John Street</p>
            </div>


              <div class="social-media">
               <h3>Follow our social media</h3> 
                <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf230;</i>
                  </div>

                   </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much more simple when you use `flexbox`, also avoid using negative margin value when you're trying to position elements

```css
#footer {
  background: #2e3131;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 165px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-contact {
  color: #fff;
}

.headquaters {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.social-media {
  float: right;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 238);
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="footer-contact">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <p>Phone: (777) 777-7777</p>
    <p>Cell: (347) 777-7777</p>
    <p>E-mail: someone@gmail.com</p>
  </div>

  <div class="headquaters">
    <h3>Locations</h3>
    <p>90 John Street</p>
  </div>


  <div class="social-media">
    <h3>Follow our social media</h3>
    <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf230;</i>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: I totally agree with your solution, but using flexbox requires more skill, I am afraid it won't be easily maintainable by a beginner.

Comment: I'm not really agree on this point, `flexbox` seems to be a little bit difficult to handle, though it's new to everyone & it defines a different mechanism on handling elements, so it puts expert & beginner not too far from each other when first being introduced to.